# Adobe Animate HTML5 Canvas issue w/ Google Chrome only. Animation is Lagging

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, html5-canvas, adobe-edge

We have published an HTML5 Canvas through Adobe Animate. And have reduced the file size down to under 2MB total and it loads in under 3 seconds on all browsers. But we are having frame (FPS) lagging issues on Google Chrome only.

We deactivated the 2D canvas chrome accelerator in Chrome Flags, but are still having issues getting the animation run smoothly at larger screen sizes.

Is there a way to publish the canvas in Animate so this doesn't happen? Or is there some JavaScript code to allow for Chrome to load the animation at the correct FPS?

We have tested in IE, Edge, and FF and all of those browsers run smoothly. It is only Google Chrome that is experiencing the issue.

Comment: After further experimentation, it seems we are also getting the lag on devices that are 4k.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Having profiled this, I have found that the code makes a large number of calls to drawImage. On my machine, it spent 86% of its time in calls to drawImage.

Its possible that its redrawing the large images every frame. See if there is a way to stop this from occurring.

Try removing the background images and having just the lines, if the lag disappears, you have your answer.

Potentially relevant:

[Why does chrome struggle to display lots of images on a canvas when the other browsers don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738438/why-does-chrome-struggle-to-display-lots-of-images-on-a-canvas-when-the-other-br?rq=1)

Comment: drawImage should be one of the fastest operations on canvas.

Comment: not if its called a billion times. This seems to be the problem. As I said, based on profiling, its using 86% of CPU cycles. Feel free to repeat the test on different hardware.